# Sum of series of coefficients of zeta in even integers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

Prove that the $\sum (2n+1) b_{2n}=\frac{1-\sin2}{1-\cos 2}$, where $b_{2n}=\pi^{-2n} \zeta(2n)$

I found in book that $b_{2m}-\frac{1}{3!}b_{2m-2}+ \frac{1}{5!}b_{2m-4}+...+(-1)^{m-1}\frac{1}{(2m-1)!}b_{2}=(-1)^{m-1}\frac{m}{(2m+1)!}$
and proved by myself that $\sum b_{2n}=\frac{\sin 1 -\cos 1}{2 \sin 1}$

Comment: Numerically, $\sum (2n+1) b_{2n}=0.56404884778436525429824751567654683084$, while $\frac{1-\sin2}{1-\cos 2}=0.064048847784365254298247515676546830955$. $\sum b_{2n}=\frac{1-\cot 1}2$, while your expression isn't even a real number. Check your sources, please!

Comment: @wasn'tme. Start the summation at $n=0$ and it works.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici For the first sum, yes, but the second is still a real number, $-\cot(1)/2$, not the complex expression given. The OP should indicate the summation bounds, indeed. Or maybe they mean *all* even numbers, including the negative ones? ;-)

Comment: @wasn'tme. I fully agree with you. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you for correcting the result of $\sum b_{n}$.  I mixed up trigonometric and hyperbolic Taylor serieses.

Answer (score 1):

[Since](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) $$\sum_{n\geq2}x^{n}\zeta\left(n\right)=-\gamma x-x\psi\left(1-x\right),\,-1\leq x<1$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\psi(x)$ is the digamma function we have, by the [multisection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection) and the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula), that $$\sum_{n\geq1}x^{2n}\zeta\left(2n\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left[1-\pi x\cot\left(\pi x\right)\right].$$ Hence $$\sum_{n\geq1}\left(2n+1\right)\pi^{-2n}\zeta\left(2n\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{2}\left[1-\pi x\cot\left(\pi x\right)\right]\right)_{x=1/\pi}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}\left(1\right)}-\frac{2\cos\left(1\right)}{\sin\left(1\right)}\right)}.$$